# Team Foundation Server 2010 Build Question

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, mstest, tfsbuild

Does anyone know if its possible to have TFS2010 Build Server run ONLY tests rather than entire project.

Here is why, I want to setup a schedule to have my server execute my tests daily, without having to make sure my entire project is fully functional, since I will be working on the code, it may not be buildable, however my tests should still work, I don't want to get bugs entered because the build failed, but i do want bugs if my tests fail

Comment: It was better to use "Is it possible to have TFS2010 Build Server run ONLY tests rather than entire project?" as question title.

Answer (score 0):

You better break your code into several projects. So you can test each one separately without worrying about build breaks.